# Tweepy information into MySQL - text being cut off

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy, pymysql

I am inserting information from twitter using Tweepy into a MySQL table. Mostly it works are intended however, the actual text from the tweet is being cut off and many end with "..." and I am not sure why this is.

An example of the output is this:

@JamesMelville: Remain voters are not "unpatriotic" by "talking the country down".Its the opposite. Remainers care about Britains fut…

Thanks for your help

Here is my stream listener class: (I am new to python so this is probably poor)

```
class listener(StreamListener):



def on_data(self, data):
    try:


        jsonData=json.loads(data)


        tweets =(jsonData['text'])

        if tweets.startswith('RT'):
            retweets = True
        else:
            retweets = False


        tweets = tweets.replace('RT', '')
        tweets = tweets.replace("'", '')
        tweets = tweets.lstrip()
        tweets = tweets.replace('\n', '')



        screen_name =(jsonData['user']['screen_name'])

        name =(jsonData['user']['name'])
        name = name.replace(',', ' ')
        language =(jsonData['lang'])

        location =(jsonData['place'])

        coord =(jsonData['coordinates'])

        device = jsonData['source'].split('">')[1].replace('</a>', '')

        tweettime = jsonData['created_at'].replace('+', '')
        tweettime = datetime.datetime.strptime(tweettime, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %f %Y")
        date_to_string = str(tweettime.strftime("%Y/%m/%d,%H:%M:%S"))
        date_created = date_to_string.split(',')[0]
        time_created = date_to_string.split(',')[1]
        created_time =(time_created)
        created_date =(date_created)

        htext = jsonData['entities']['hashtags']
        htext2 = []
        hashtag_list = ''
        for hashtag in htext:
            htext=str(hashtag['text'])
            hashtag_list = hashtag_list + ' ::' + htext
        hashtag_list = hashtag_list.replace("'", "")






        conn = connect( host = '', port = , user = ', passwd = '', charset='utf8', autocommit = True);
        conn.commit()
        cursor = conn.cursor( cursors.DictCursor );

        cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS twitter")
        cursor.execute("USE twitter")
        cursor.execute( """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `twitter_data`(ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,`Name` VARCHAR( 200 ) ,`Screen name` VARCHAR( 200 ) , `Date created` VARCHAR ( 20 ), `Time created` VARCHAR ( 8 ), Tweet VARCHAR ( 200 ), Hashtags VARCHAR ( 200 ), Retweets VARCHAR ( 5 ), Lanugage VARCHAR ( 20 ), Device VARCHAR ( 60 ), Location VARCHAR( 200 ), Coordinates VARCHAR ( 200 ), PRIMARY KEY ( ID ))""" )
        sql = "INSERT INTO `twitter_data` VALUES( Null, '" + str(name) + "', '" + str(screen_name) + "', '" + str(created_date) + "', '" + str(created_time) + "', '" + str(tweets) + "', '" + str(hashtag_list) + "', '" + str(retweets) + "', '" + str(language) + "', '" + str(device) + "', '" + str(location) + "', '" + str(coord) + "') "
        print(sql)
        cursor.execute(sql)

        return True
    except Exception as N:
        print('failed on_data '+ str(N))
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: You will have to give an example record of your `...` part (real output copied from console)

Comment: Here is an example: @astro_trader: #brexit is not knee-jerk reaction, its result of 40 yrs pent-up anger &amp; frustration of having UK sovereignty given away…

Comment: or this: @JamesMelville: Remain voters are not "unpatriotic" by "talking the country down".Its the opposite. Remainers care about Britains fut…

Comment: Despite that those are possible examples of ... and tweets I was more thinking in the direction of code.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean, sorry

Comment: I have solved the problem, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my question.
The text was being truncated when it was a retweet due to the 140 character limit.
Therefore it from nothing to do with MySQL.
My solution was to use the 'retweet_status' attribute (and split out the actual tweet text part) rather than 'text' if the tweet was a retweet, otherwise I just used 'text'.
Here is some of the code that was changed:

```
if tweets.startswith('RT'):
    retweets = True
    tweets = str(jsonData['retweeted_status']).split('\'text\':')[1]

    if 'display_text_range' in tweets:
        tweets = tweets.split(', \'display_text_range\'')[0]
    else:
        tweets = tweets.split(', \'source\'')[0]
else:
    retweets = False
    tweets = tweets.replace('RT', '')
```